# Websockets as source of events for AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-lambda, cometd, bayeux

Is there any chance that things like WebSockets, the Bayeux protocol, or long polling techniques, in general, could be used as a source of events to trigger AWS Lambdas? (without implementing an EC2-based listener)

Comment: No. You would need an EC2-based listener.